# VS2010 - NuGet error with proxy - "ttp" scheme

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget

I'm seeing an issue when using the NuGet package manager. I'm selecting the "Tools" menu and then "Manage NuGet packages for solution". The NuGet version is 2.1.31002.9028.

When selecting anything from the "Online" or "Updates" options I see an error in the main pain that reads "The ServicePointManager does not support proxies with the **ttp** scheme".

Note the "ttp" part...which should surely be "http". Where would I change this though. In Internet Explorers setting the proxy server does not have a prefix (and I can't change this as it's locked down). I've tried adding the proxy manually by editing the devenv.exe.config as advised here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10829550  but not joy.

Does anyone know where else the ServicePointManager would be grabbing this URL?

Thanks,

James.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved this issue by going back to 1.7.30402.9028 available here: http://nuget.codeplex.com/downloads/get/382255

I did initially try version 1.8 but received an error relating to a non-supported cryptographic type and so went to 1.7.