# NuGet behind firewall

Tags: nuget, firewall

I am trying to use nuget behind a firewall.
I have access to nuget.org on ports 80 and port 443.
I see all packages with Nuget.exe  list, but I fail to install packages with the bad error message "Unable to connect to the remote server".
Do I need to add additional ports/domains to the firewall config?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a proxy server set ? Can you try setting it as per details here in the other thread @ [Accessing Nuget Official Package Source behind company proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710533/accessing-nuget-official-package-source-behind-company-proxy) ?