# How can I not see the following error when loading from nuget?

Tags: c#, nuget

When I download from Nuget, I get the following error

> [nuget.org] Unable to load the service index for source
> https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.   An error occurred while sending
> the request.   Unable to connect to the remote server   A connection
> attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond
> after a period of time, or established connection failed because
> connected host has failed to respond 148.251.160.242:443

please help me

Comment: You are probably behind a proxy. So it depends how you use nuget (via Visual Studio, via Command line or something else). You can use [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232160/nuget-behind-a-proxy) or [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710533/accessing-nuget-official-package-source-behind-company-proxy) as a starting point.

Comment: You are having an issue with the TLS/SSL secure part of the connection.  what version of TLS/SSL are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the proxy settings in your nuget.config file. Check [this](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/schema/nuget.config-file#config-section)